# Trouble understanding the Principle of Induction

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

I have trouble understanding the Theorem 2.1 in Peter J. Camerons "Sets, Logic and Categories".

**The Theorem:**

Let $(X,<)$ be a well ordered set, and $Y$ a subset of $X$ with the property:

$\forall x \in X:((\forall y < x:y \in Y) \Longrightarrow x \in Y) \Longrightarrow Y = X $

**My difficulty:**

As far as I understand it, it says that if for all $x$ in $X$, the property that all $y$ smaller than $x$ are in the subset $Y$ implies that $x$ is in $Y$, then $Y$ is equal to $X$.

But how can $x$ itself even be in the subset $Y$ if we define $Y$ to be consisting of all elements $y$ smaller than $x$?

Comment: Are you saying that it looks like "let $x_0$ be some element of $X$, and let $Y$ be the set of all $y \in X$ with $y < x_0$" provides a counterexample? In fact it doesn't! This choice of $Y$ does not satisfy the LHS of this implication, precisely because $x = x_0$ is not in $Y$.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean! Because if the implication in the middle was false for any $x \in X$, that would mean that $X$ and $Y$ have to be different.

Comment: "we define Y to be consisting of all elements y smaller than x?" This would be $\forall y \in Y: y < x$, which is different from what's in the statement: $\forall x < y: y\in Y$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I understand what you are getting at, but i think you made a typo: Did you mean to say $\forall y < x : y \in Y$ in the last line?

Comment: @schrattinger yes I did.